# C++ Error: Expected unqualified-id and use of undeclared identifier error?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I get repeated errors like this:
`error: use of undeclared identifier 'item'` and
`"error: expected unqualified-id`
`cin.getline(*(cart->(item+i)->itemName), SIZE1);`. When I used pointer notation with the arrow operator when accessing a struct within a struct. I understand that I am only filling in some of the members of the cart variable of the ShoppingCart type, but I don't see the problem to be coming from here. It looks like the way I am accessing the members of the item variable of the ItemInfo type is wrong. Though, I don't know where my error is. If someone could help me, it would be greatly appreciated. My code is here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE1 = 51,
          SIZE2 = 11,
          SIZE3 = 21;
struct ItemInfo
{
  char itemName[SIZE1];
  char itemID[SIZE2];
  double price;
};
struct ShoppingCart
{
  char shopperName[SIZE3];
  ItemInfo *item;
  int *itemCount;
  double total;
};
void addToCart(ShoppingCart* cart);

int main()
{
  ShoppingCart* cart = new ShoppingCart;

  cart->item = nullptr;

  addToCart(cart);

  delete [] cart->item;
  delete [] cart->itemCount;
  delete cart;
  return 0;
}

void addToCart(ShoppingCart* cart)
{
  int numItems;

  cout << "How many items are you purchasing?";
  cin >> numItems;

  cart->item = new ItemInfo[numItems];
  cart->itemCount = new int[numItems];

  for(int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
  {
    cout << "\nEnter #" << i+1 << " item name: ";
    cin.getline(*(cart->(item+i)->itemName), SIZE1);

    cout << "\nEnter #" << i+1 << " item ID: ";
    cin.getline(*(cart->(item+i)->itemID), SIZE2);

    cout << "\nEnter #" << i+1 << " price: ";
    cin >> *(cart->(item+i)->price);
    cin.ignore();

    cout << "\nEnter #" << i+1 << " quantity: ";
    cin >> *(cart->itemCount+i);
    cin.ignore();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `cart->item[i]`, which is more readable and easily gets the precedence right.

If you still want or need to use addition with pointers, you need to place the parentheses differently:

```
(cart->item+i)->itemName
```

because `item` is a member of the ShoppingCart `cart`.

Comment: This helped me debug my code. Thank you! It is working now with a little more tweaking:
```    cout << "\nEnter #" << i+1 << " item name: ";
    cin.getline((cart->item+i)->itemName, SIZE1);
    
    cout << "\nEnter #" << i+1 << " item ID: ";
    cin.getline((cart->item+i)->itemID, SIZE2);

    cout << "\nEnter #" << i+1 << " price: ";
    cin >> (cart->item+i)->price;
    cin.ignore(); ```